# TypeError: 'setSolc' is not a function

Tags: solc

I am trying to sync geth and solc.

```
which solc # I get the path to my solc
/usr/local/bin/solc
```

Open the geth console

```
geth console 2>>geth.log
```

and now I try to sync

```
admin.setSolc("/usr/local/bin/solc")
```

but I get the error

```
TypeError: 'setSolc' is not a function
at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Comment: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs

Answer (score 3):

I believe `solc` integration was removed from `geth` as of [v1.6.0](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases/tag/v1.6.0).  See [#3740](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/3740) for more details, but it looks like `admin.setSolc` was removed as part of that PR.

Comment: Thank you @DeviateFish, so how could I possisble link Solc to Geth..?

Comment: In general, solc should be used as a standalone tool, or via tools built around it (e.g. browser-solidity)

Comment: There are tutorials everywhere referencing it.  Is there a consistent help page/tutorial so I can deploy a contract?

Comment: @JustinThomas Yeah, the tutorials are now all considered "out of date", as of `geth` v1.6.0 (as linked above).  I don't know of any tutorials off the top of my head, but if you look for ones that are specific to `solc` itself (e.g. using the command line), you might find what you're looking for.